# Is it possible to delete my Facebook account and not lose the info synced to my Evo?

Tags: sync, htc-evo, facebook

Last weekend I turned off the automatic sync feature on my phone and deleted my Facebook account. It appeared that all of the info on in my calendar was still there so I thought I did all that I needed to do. By this weekend all of my birthdays and events were deleted from my calendar - except 3 that were linked to Facebook - and all the ones that I manually entered (**not** linked to Facebook) were gone! I tried to reactivate my Facebook account, and re-sync everything to get the info back, but its not working.

How do I get the info back into my calendar, and delete my Facebook account/remove the Facebook app and sync stuff from my phone? Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your phones calendar is syncing with a Google Calendar, then the easiest way to do this may be to export your friends' birthday info from Facebook and import it into Google Calendar.

Our sister-site Web Applications has more info on doing this:

- [How do you extract friends' birthday and contact information from Facebook?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/6274)
- [Import birthdays of friends from Facebook into Google Calendar?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/6954)